# Injecting IOptions config always returning null in .razor file

Tags: c#, .net, razor, dependency-injection, blazor

I'm fairly new to .NET and am working on an existing project. I've setup a configuration class that works perfectly when injecting into a service like so:

```
public PayPalConnection(IOptions<PayPalConfiguration> config) { 
   DoSomething(config.Value.SomeValue);
}
```

However, I'm having some trouble getting it to work on my Razor pages. I would expect this to work (given that I can access SomeValue on my service without issue):

```
@inject IOptions<PayPalConfiguration> Configuration;
<div> @Configuration.Value.SomeValue</div>
```

But this always returns null. I have also tried things like

```
@inject IConfiguration Config
<div>@Config["PayPal:SomeValue"]</div>
```

But that too returns nothing. I've tried with other configuration classes that are setup, and it seems that any configuration I try to use in my razor pages is always null. Any recommendations are much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you make sure you've registered `IOptions<PayPalConfiguration>` with DI in your startup / program?

Comment: Hi Luke, I have it registered like this in Startup.cs services.Configure<PayPalConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("paypal")); inside the ConfigureServicesIServiceCollection services) method

Comment: In which Startup in which project? Do you have a Solution with a Client and a Server?

Comment: Ah, that may be the issue. I have a "Web" Solution where the Startup.cs sets the config, and a "WebClient" Solution where the Pages/*.razor reside...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Henk Holterman I realized I was trying to access the configuration of my Web (Server) Solution from my WebClient Solution so it was returning null. I fixed this by using an HttpClient to fetch what I needed from the Web Solution and that resolved my issue.